# Can't programmatically open PDF to a named destination

Tags: c++, pdf, visual-c++, mfc

I use `ShellExecute` to open up my PDF. `Pathname` has the URL to the PDF and `#nameddest=nameddestination` to specify the location to open to. However, every time I open the PDF with `ShellExcecute`, it only opens to the first page rather than the location of the `nameddestination`.

```
CString PathName = _T("file:///C:/Users/Linh.Ly/Documents/TestFile.pdf#nameddest=nameddestination");
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), PathName, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: When you paste this url to the browser, does it go to that location?

Comment: What _exactly_ does `PathName` point to?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It opens to the PDF and to the named destination. So yes

Comment: @Jabberwocky file:///C:/Users/Linh.Ly/Documents/TestFile.pdf#nameddest=nameddestination

Comment: @LinhLy you should mention that in the question. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: What program is opening the PDF? Do you have any evidence that it supports this syntax?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Opening the PDF in a MFC application

Comment: No. You are calling `ShellExecute` from your MFC application. What program is then responding to that shell verb and opening and displaying the PDF. Do you have any evidence that it supports this syntax?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, Adobe Acrobat Pro. I fixed the problem. ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), "Acrobat.exe", Parameters, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);  I just had to put the parameters for the PDF pathname into there.

Comment: @LinhLy you can answer your own question

Comment: What happens if the program runs on a machine that does not have Acrobat Pro installed on it?